# How to align the multiple author in scrbook/ book styles?

Tags: table-of-contents, scrbook

Here are my codes...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true,openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz,lipsum}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}}
\def\inst#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\address#1{\textit{#1}}
\def\email#1{\texttt{#1}}
\def\aut#1{\textbf{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}
 \makeatletter \renewcommand\@dotsep{300}
\def\insti#1{\textit{#1}\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection}{#1}{}}}

% % % % % % % %Abstract Environment % % % % % % % %
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\newcommand\abstractname{Abstract}  %%% here
\makeatletter
  \newenvironment{abstract}{%
      \if@twocolumn
        \section*{\abstractname}%
      \else
        \small
        \begin{center}%
          {\bfseries \abstractname\vspace{-.5em}\vspace{\z@}}%
        \end{center}%
        \quotation
      \fi}
      {\if@twocolumn\else\endquotation\fi}
%\fi
\makeatother
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %

\begin{document}
\chapter{Abstracts}
\tableofcontents
\section{Measures of agreement in ordinal scale between multiple raters in thyroid patients}
\aut{First author$^1$, Second Author$^2$, Third author$^3$}\\
\inst{$^1$Department of Biostatistics, $^2$Department of Radiology, $^3$ Department of Mathematics}\\
\address{1st address, 2nd address, 3rd address.}
%        
        \begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

This is my out put...

[image]

### Question

> 1. How to align the author names properly, without affecting the table content entries?
> 2. I know in the article class we have  \and command to split the author names.. Can I use like the same command to split the name,
>      instituition, address across the page..

That is like this...

[image]

### Mywork:

I have used the following commands to align the authors name under the section title as shown in the above pic...
but i am not getting the proper output in table of contents...
the following are the codes I used for the above output..

```
\section{Measures of agreement in ordinal scale between multiple raters in thyroid patients}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\aut{First author$^1$ }\\
\inst{Department of Biostatistics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\aut {Second Author$^2$,}\\
\inst{Department of Radiology}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author2@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.35\textwidth}
\aut {Third author$^3$}\\
\inst{Department of Mathematics}\\
\address{first line\\second line\\ third line}\\
\email{author3@gmail.com}
\end{minipage}
```

Comment: Is there any news here? The question seems answerable, though the input would change a bit.